# Actionscript: TypeError: Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, button, actionscript, error-handling

I have been trying to fix an error in my project for the past hour, and I really have no idea what the cause is. I will post the code on my skydrive:

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=9AB08B59DCCDF9C6&resid=9AB08B59DCCDF9C6%21108&authkey=AGVkp5KnQLMYu7M

Everything just doesn't work the way I want to. The inventoryrelationships_btn is glitchy when I test the movie. To make it worse, when I debug, and the inventory/relationships button is clicked, it freezes up everything.

Comment: Hmm ... I am not seeing the issue with your FLA, no 1009 error.  Have you updated your Flash IDE lately?  I am on Flash Pro CS6

Comment: The error is in output, and it freezes in debug? That did not happen?

Comment: Got it, and found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit comes from the following line

```
menuback_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, menubackClick);
```

in your "popups" symbol, frame 2.  There is no menuback_btn, and if you do a    trace(menuback_btn); The output window shows null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but if my menuback_btn shows up in frame 3, what do I do about that? I can't repeat my coding(put it on two seperate frames I mean), or it I will get a duplicate function error?